# How to declare more than one option for SCNPhysicsShape

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I need to declare both ShapeTypeKey as well as ShapeScaleKey in [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry: options:] all options that come to mind come up short. For example my current code is similar to;

```
NSValue *nodeScale = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector3:SCNVector3Make(200, 400, 150)];
SCNScene *stackScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"stackoverflow.dae"];
SCNNode *stackNode = [stackScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"Grid" recursively:NO];
SCNGeometry *nodeGeometry = stackNode.geometry;

stackNode.physicsBody.physicsShape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:nodeGeometry options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron}];
stackNode.physicsBody.physicsShape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:nodeGeometry options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey:nodeScale}];
```

This obviously overwrites the former with the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being it's a dictionary, you can do something like this:

```
stackNode.physicsBody.physicsShape = [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:nodeGeometry options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron, SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey:nodeScale}];
```

Each element in a dictionary can be separated with a comma